# Redmine on Windows using "thin": session gets shared between instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, thin

I am trying to setup two redmine 2.0.3 instances using thin on windows 2008.

I am starting thin with

```
D:\redmine1>thin start -e production -p 3005 --prefix /redmine/instance1
D:\redmine2>thin start -e production -p 3006 --prefix /redmine/instance2
```

to start the instances. When I login into one instance **I am automatically logged in with the same username into the other instance**. The session in in the session cookie '_redmine_session' is the same (because the cookie points to '/').

Is this a thin problem oder redmine problem? The secret tokens in the configuration.yml are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that i had copied the directory and regenerated the token via

```
rake generate_secret_token
```

but this did not overwrite the generated file "secret.rb". I had to manually delete the file. There was not even an error message, so i opened a redmine ticket for this.

[Ticket: #11866](http://www.redmine.org/issues/11866)